# Is it thread safe to reinitialize a concurentbag?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I have one writer and multiple readers of a concurrentbag.

The writer periodically refreshes the complete contents of the concurrentbag from a database.

Is it thread safe to reinitialize (ie = new concurrentbag) within the writer thread? If not, I see the only option being to lock it during all reads and writes which rather defeats the point. I can't iterate over the bag to empty it a piece at a time because any reads dung that process would then base their behaviour upon partial information.

Thank you all!

Comment: What's your worry? That some reader thread might initiate the reading operation on one instance of `ConcurrentBag<>` and then finish the same read on another instance? Or are you afraid the thread won't pick up the new reference? Maybe you want a `volatile` field (if this is a field at all)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Jeppe. My concern is that the reinitialization will happen during a read and an exception will ensue.

Comment: You are updating a reference when you do this, that's atomic in .NET.  The outcome is of course random, exactly how many objects from the old bag are consumed is entirely unpredictable.  Very hard to see how that could be acceptable behavior, it just never is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this has nothing to do with the `ConcurrentBag` type. It, alone, will be completely safe regarding this.

If on one thread a method call is being done on the bag, while at the same time on another thread you do this:

```
_BagField = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
```

Then the method call on the first thread will complete just fine, but *on the old instance*.

However, *this* is not safe, but due to the reasons for using the type in the first place, *never was*:

```
if (_BagField.Any())
    var percentage = 100 / _BagField.Count(); // broken
```

This might call `.Any()` on one instance, and `.Count()` on another, but this has never been safe since there is no safeguards to ensure that Count doesn't fall to zero just after you have called `Any`.

Note, however, that you have no guarantees that other threads will pick up the new instance right away.

For instance, this:

```
string temp;
while (!_Bag.TryTake(out temp))
{
    // process temp
}
```

might never get to the new instance and will continue processing the old bag instance before just stopping dead.

To ensure that, make sure the field containing the bag reference is [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Lasse. So, were I to make my concurrentbag volatile, and within my reading thread perform a copy (for example ToList), then operate on that copy, it would be guaranteed to be a full set of data as it was either before or after the writer thread reinitialised it. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, in terms of replacing the instance, however, I don't know how `ToList` and `ConcurrentBag` works together, so you may want to ensure that `ToList` is thread-safe at all, not regarding replacing the whole instance, but whether it will handle that another thread modifies the bag at the same time.

Comment: Super duper. Thank you!